# Uncaught TypeError: canvas1.position is not a function in p5.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, p5.js

I am trying to make program using p5.js and javascript. But I got a problem in p5.dom.js and got error like:

> "Uncaught TypeError: canvas1.position is not a function"

And i almost consume a day :(

I was about to make another js file using p5.js.

Here is my code!

**main.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=1200 height=1334></canvas>
        <script src="coords.js"></script>
        <script src="p5/p5/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="p5/p5/p5.dom.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**coords.js**

```
if(flag==1 && count==2){
    $('body').append('<script src="sketch.js"></script>');
        $.getScript("p5/p5/p5.min.js")
            .done(function(){
            $.getScript("p5/p5/p5.dom.js")
                .done(function(){
                $.getScript("sketch.js",function(){
                    setup();
                });
            }); 
    });
}
```

**sketch.js**

```
var canvas1;
function setup(){
    canvas1=createCanvas(width1,height1);
    canvas1.position(minX1,maxY1);//got error here!!
}
```

Please help me!!

Comment: try put <script src="coords.js"></script> below <script src="p5/p5/p5.dom.js"></script>

Comment: @Ollaw it's not working....

Comment: What and why is `coords.js`?

Comment: Try leaving `coords.js` out altogether. Put `sketch.js` in after the `p5` scripts and only run the `setup` function when your `if` condition is matched.

Comment: @Craicerjack There are another functions in coords.js but I ddn't upload up there....

Comment: @Craicerjack Put sketch.js in where?

Answer (score 0):

Okay given that `coords` has other code you should probably do something like this:
Include `sketch.js` as normal, and put it after the `p5` files.
Then include `coords` as normal

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas" width=1200 height=1334></canvas>
        <script src="p5/p5/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="p5/p5/p5.dom.js"></script>
        <script src="sketch.js"></script>
        <script src="coords.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then your `coords.js` can look like this:

```
if(flag==1 && count==2){
    setup();
}
```

This way you dont have strange and unnecessary ajax calls loading code youre already loading.

#### EDIT

Given that `setup()` runs by default you should be able to put `setup` within your if condition and remove `sketch.js` altogether.

```
if(flag==1 && count==2){
    var canvas1;
    function setup(){
        canvas1=createCanvas(width1,height1);
        canvas1.position(minX1,maxY1);//got error here!!
    }
}
```

or as answered by g aand

```
if (flag == 1 && count == 2) {
    $('body').append('<script src="sketch.js"></script>');
}
```

or you could [use a namespace](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace):

```
var s = function( p ) {
    var x = 100; 
    var y = 100;
    
    p.setup = function() {
        p.createCanvas(x, y);
        p.position(x,y);
    };
    
    p.draw = function() {
        p.background(0);
        p.fill(255);
        p.rect(x,y,50,50);
    };
};

if (flag == 1 && count == 2) {
    var myp5 = new p5(s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you but sketch.js should execute in condition:if(flag==1 && count==2) , otherwise canvas in sketch.js come out :(

Comment: Have you tried it, because `setup()` in `sketch.js` is only called if it meets your conditions, unless there is more code than you are showing...

Comment: @user8014056 You could try moving your setup into the `conditional` or you could set up an object to hold it and then only instantiate it when the conditional is met - [instantiation with a namespace](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace)